# JSON.parse is not giving consistent result

Tags: javascript, json, next.js, cookies, jwt

I am storing data in Cookie using the js-cookie package in my Nextjs project.
After getting data from the backend service.
I am getting the details in JSON format

```
data={
    token: "abc",
    user:{
      name: "ab",
      email:"a@gmail.com",
      subscribed:{
        enddate:"yyyy-mm-dd"
      }
    }
  }
```

After getting the details I am storing the data in

```
Cookies.set("user", JSON.stringify({ data }), {
    expires: 7,
  });
```

and parsing the data to get the details of the user stored in the cookie

```
 try {
        let user = Cookies.get("user");
        let userDetails = JSON.parse(user);
        return userDetails;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
```

But after parsing sometimes it's parsing the data and sometimes it's throwing error.

```
  SyntaxError {
    stack: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0\n' +
      '    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)\n' +
      '    at eval (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/
```

[Syntax Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFdLa.png)

I tried changing the data because token contained '.'

I thought maybe becaues of that might be one of the reasons for error.

Tried storing separately token and the userDetails but in both cases was getting error at the time of parsing.

Not able to find the possible cause

Open to other solutions to store the user data in the browser.

Comment: Try `console.log(user)` once you `Cookies.get`. It may give an hint.

Comment: (1) `data={
    token: "abc",` is not valid JSON. (2) check what  `Cookies.get("user")` returns. Probably not valid JSON either.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv but OP stringifies that before setting their cookie.

Comment: no sure why the curly brakets here `JSON.stringify({ data })` but it is definitely stringified

Comment: Yeah I guess he's showing us the JS that represents this data, not the JSON string received from the API. The extra wrapping can also be ignored. Only thing that really matters is what `Cookies.get` returns... I have a hunch it's the string `"undefined"`.

Comment: @ShriHariL  I have tried console.log it gives similar to this
'{"_id":"64f8feae11a","name":"CLover","email":"clover@gmail.com"}'

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv the Cookie is not being sent from the backend it's being set in the frontend only. I am not sure but in that case, it shouldn't return undefined right.

Comment: @Clover always? Because in your question you are saying that sometimes JSON.parse works and other times it does not. Which means sometimes Cookies.get returns valid JSON and otherwise it does not. Which is not helpful unless you log what Cookies.get returns and check the logged value when JSON.parse fails. After you figure out what Cookies.get returns you want to dig deeper and figure out what values Cookies.set sets... Are you sure there's always a value?